# Safely generating multiple controls from a list of variables

Tags: dynamic

Suppose I need to create sliders associated with variables from a given list:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d];
vars = {a, b, c, d};
Slider[Dynamic@#, {0, 1}] & /@ vars
Dynamic@vars
```

Unfortunately it works only for variables which don't have values:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d];
vars = {a, b, c, d};
a = 1;
Slider[Dynamic@#, {0, 1}] & /@ vars
Dynamic@vars
```

As you can see now the first slider is not working because Mma attempts to assign values to raw object `1` instead of `a`. Nevertheless simple

```
Slider[Dynamic@a, {0, 1}]
Dynamic@a
```

produces the desired result.

So, what is the right way to do such things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way may be to avoid such constructs, but, if you insist on using a list of variables like that, here is one way:

```
Thread[Hold[vars] /. OwnValues[vars]] /. Hold[v_] :> Slider[Dynamic[v], {0, 1}]
```

You can store variables wrapped in `Hold` rather than `List`, in which case the first step (involving `OwnValues`) can be skipped.

Comment: @Leonid, thank you. Could you explain what's wrong with this construct?

Comment: @Rojo I actually think that one just should find other ways to achieve the desired result (avoid solving this problem altogether). Storing variables in a list and then looking for ways to avoid evaluation seems like an unnecessary extra work to me.

Comment: @faleichik Well, see my comment above. If you have several (many) variables, perhaps it is better to define a list (array) and index it to access individual variables, or use indexed variables. Having a separate variable to store a list of named variables which can evaluate, seems more complex and error-prone to me.

Comment: Ok, I have to agree with you. Anyway using variable names instead of indices is sometimes more convenient for quick sketches.  As you've said, using `Hold` instead of `List` is a good alternative.